# Ancient civilizations question

Tags: history

What happened after great mahabharat war in other parts/countries of the world in ancient time means which dynasty or civilization were left or were ruling others countries/parts of the world?

Comment: Read on: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc116018.html